# How to create an envelope with signingGroup recipient?

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an envelope using this uri:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
```

**headers**:

```
Content-Type : application/json
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username" : *****, "Password" : ******, "IntegratorKey" : *********}
```

**body**:

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Signing Request for Doc2.docx",
  "signerCanSignOnMobile": "true",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "384098342",
      "name": "Doc2.docx",
      "fileExtension": "docx",
      "documentBase64": *****,
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "xPosition": "2",
            "yPosition": "3",
            "documentId": "384098342",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "value": "Fill in name.",
            "locked": "false",
            "anchorString": "sign5",
            "anchorXOffset": "1.75",
            "anchorYOffset": "0",
            "anchorUnits": "inches",
            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "name": "Tom Ford",
        "email": "tom.ford@email.com",
        "recipientId": "64000",
        "clientUserId": "c7052b97-f9a7-4af4-85de-8c64371467b1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Demand Approvers",
        "email": "approvers@email.com",
        "signingGroupId": "true",
        "signingGroupName": "Demand Approvers",
        "recipientId": "626000",
        "clientUserId": "123c6d15-1d25-4595-9878-5cbda4ba2823",
        "signingGroupUsers": [
          {
            "userName": "John Smith",
            "userId": "9c328221-1e86-41db-a3e7-bde9b4b4a50d",
            "email": "josmith@example.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the request succeeds. However, when I try to query the returned envelope, the "Demand Approvers" is listed as a single recipient instead of as a signingGroup.
Here is an example output:

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "documentsUri": "/envelopes/063454a6-dee6-4e86-8d38-56d85e66c61e/documents",
  "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/063454a6-dee6-4e86-8d38-56d85e66c61e/recipients",
  "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/063454a6-dee6-4e86-8d38-56d85e66c61e/attachments",
  "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/063454a6-dee6-4e86-8d38-56d85e66c61e",
  "emailSubject": "Signing Request for Doc2.docx",
  "envelopeId": "063454a6-dee6-4e86-8d38-56d85e66c61e",
  "signingLocation": "online",
  "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/063454a6-dee6-4e86-8d38-56d85e66c61e/custom_fields",
  "notificationUri": "/envelopes/063454a6-dee6-4e86-8d38-56d85e66c61e/notification",
  "enableWetSign": "true",
  "allowMarkup": "false",
  "allowReassign": "true",
  "createdDateTime": "2021-02-17T00:43:28.7070000Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-02-17T00:43:28.7230000Z",
  "initialSentDateTime": "2021-02-17T00:43:29.2570000Z",
  "sentDateTime": "2021-02-17T00:43:29.2570000Z",
  "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-02-17T00:43:29.2570000Z",
  "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/********************/documents/combined",
  "certificateUri": "/envelopes/********************/documents/certificate",
  "templatesUri": "/envelopes/********************/templates",
  "expireEnabled": "true",
  "expireDateTime": "2021-06-17T00:43:29.2570000Z",
  "expireAfter": "120",
  "sender": {
    "userName": "********",
    "userId": "********",
    "accountId": "********",
    "email": "sender@email.com"
  },
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "creationReason": "sender",
        "isBulkRecipient": "false",
        "recipientSuppliesTabs": "true",
        "requireUploadSignature": "false",
        "name": "Demand Approvers",
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "email": "approvers@email.com",
        "recipientId": "626000",
        "recipientIdGuid": "365b2f4d-0968-42d1-805e-55eece700246",
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "userId": "891a3891-f49d-4f14-8bc8-959524e2445a",
        "clientUserId": "123c6d15-1d25-4595-9878-5cbda4ba2823",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "status": "sent",
        "completedCount": "0",
        "deliveryMethod": "email",
        "recipientType": "signer"
      },
      {
        "creationReason": "sender",
        "isBulkRecipient": "false",
        "recipientSuppliesTabs": "true",
        "requireUploadSignature": "false",
        "name": "Tom Ford",
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "email": "tom.ford@email.com",
        "recipientId": "64000",
        "recipientIdGuid": "c60c5ccd-e49f-4b63-9745-5f283b8520eb",
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "userId": "4a78d305-43bf-4d78-a844-2bdc15e63770",
        "clientUserId": "c7052b97-f9a7-4af4-85de-8c64371467b1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "status": "sent",
        "completedCount": "0",
        "deliveryMethod": "email",
        "recipientType": "signer"
      }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "seals": [],
    "witnesses": [],
    "notaries": [],
    "recipientCount": "2",
    "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
  },
  "purgeState": "unpurged",
  "envelopeIdStamping": "true",
  "is21CFRPart11": "false",
  "signerCanSignOnMobile": "true",
  "autoNavigation": "true",
  "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
  "hasFormDataChanged": "false",
  "allowComments": "true",
  "hasComments": "false",
  "allowViewHistory": "true",
  "envelopeMetadata": {
    "allowAdvancedCorrect": "true",
    "enableSignWithNotary": "true",
    "allowCorrect": "true"
  },
  "anySigner": null,
  "envelopeLocation": "current_site",
  "isDynamicEnvelope": "false"
}
```

The signingGroup related information for Demand Approvers is missing.
How do I structure my request so that the Demand Approvers will be listed as a signingGroup?

Comment: Should you pass the actual signing group ID instead of `true`?

Comment: thank you @rocky! I got a clue thanks to your comment!

Comment: Your example shows that you're using legacy authentication. That is not allowed for new integrations. Please use OAuth. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause. So it seems that when dealing with Signing Groups,
These 2 points must be true:

1. The Signing Group must be registered in DocuSign. The generated
   signingGroupId can then be used as recipient. Setting signingGroupId
   to "true" or any random value will not work.
2. clientUserId must not be provided